# SSMA 18.8 - No column returned from DB2 table?

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, db2-400

I am trying to migrate a DB2 table on a System i to SQL Server 2019.  The migration assistant returns this error from DB2.

Unable to show data for the unloaded table for the following reason: Loading columns for table or view failed.
Column or global variable *N not found. SQLSTATE: 42703, SQLCODE: -206||No columns were returned from the database for table.

How do i correct this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the assistant made an SQL query that was not valid on System i (select on a NULL column) when it discovers table structure.

This issue is fixed on the latest version of SSMA for DB2 (v8.20) : "Fix tables discovery for DB2 for i".
I updated to the v8.20 and it works for me.

You can check the changelog in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/db2/what-s-new-in-ssma-for-db2-db2tosql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

42703 means that an dastabase object doesnt exist. That means that your column cant be selected. see: [docs](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=codes-sqlstate-values-common-error)